# C++11 Variable Initialization and Declaration

Tags: c++, c++11, coding-style

With C++11 came a new way to initialize and declare variables.

Original

```
int c_derived = 0;
```

C++11

```
int modern{0};
```

What are the pros and cons of each method, if there are any? Why implement a new method? Does the compiler do anything different?

Comment: The C++11 new feature may be confusing as it looks similar to a function declaration !

Comment: I think you meant to say `int modern{0};`

Comment: This existed pre-C++11. The braces are what were added.

Comment: use the readable one `int x = 0` IMO

Comment: Okay. Thanks. The book I was reading had () instead if the braces and said it was new.

Comment: The "modern" approach is more "modern", so it must be better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're mistaken -- the `int modern(0)` form (with round brackets) was available in older versions of C++, and continues to be available in C++11.

In C++11, the new form uses curly brackets to provide uniform initialisation, so you say

```
int modern{0};
```

The main advantage of this new form is that it can be consistently used everywhere. It makes it clear that you're initialising a new object, rather than calling a function or, worse, [declaring one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

It also provides syntactical consistency with C-style ("aggregate") struct initialisation, of the form

```
struct A
{
    int a; int b;
};

A a = { 1, 2 };
```

There are also more strict rules with regard to narrowing conversions of numeric types when the curly-bracket form is used.

Comment: Okay. The book I was reading used the () instead if {}. Is this more of a personal preference or will int A = 1; become deprecated in the future? Should I switch to the new method?

Comment: I don't think so. I think that c++ 11 brace-init's most significant advantage is an ability which can call default constructor. http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1852519 So, the initialization of fundamental types uses the equal sign(=) will be never deprecated.

Comment: Using curly braces also avoid narrowing conversions:
http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#narrowing

Answer (score 3):

Using braces was just an attempt to introduce universal initialization in C++11.

Now you can use braces to initialize arrays,variables,strings,vectors.