# Is there a difference between int x{}; and int x = 0;?

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization

I understood that `int x{};` is a kind of default-initialization, but is it exactly the same as writing `int x = 0;` ?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The result is same in this case.

> `int x{};` is a kind of default-initialization

Not exactly. See [default initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization).

`int x{};` is [value initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) (since C++11),

> This is the initialization performed when a variable is constructed with an empty initializer.

And the effects of value initialization in this case (i.e. neither class type nor array type) are:

> 4) otherwise, the object is **zero-initialized**.

Finally the effects of [zero initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization) in this case are:

> If T is a scalar type, the object's initial value is the **integral
>   constant zero** explicitly converted to T.

On the other hand, `int x = 0;` is [copy initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization); `x` is initialized with the value `0`.

As @PaulR mentioned, there's a difference that `int x{};` is only supported from c++11, while `int x = 0` has not such restriction.

Comment: Isn't it true that `int x{}` is supported in C++11 and later only though ? For people who need to write portable code that works with older C++ standards might not there be a case for preferring `int x = 0` ?

Comment: @PaulR Added as the difference between them.

Answer (score 8):

In this case they are identical. `int x{}` will initialise `x` in the same way as `static int x` would; i.e. to zero. That said, I find `int x = 0` clearer and it has the benefit that it works with older C++ standards.

Answer (score 8):

There is difference:
`int x=1.888;`  will work with x as 1. Lot of trouble later.All professional guys have sometime faced , in their or others' code.

but
`int x{1.888};`   will NOT compile and save trouble.

Comment: There's a related question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20603403/c11-variable-initialization-and-declaration

Answer (score 2):

They are both the exact same thing. They will both be initialized to `0`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int y{};
  int x = 0;

  cout << "y: " << y << endl;
  cout << "x: " << x << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
y: 0
x: 0
```

Comment: Please consider improving this answer by adding relevant references, which explain that output of this code follows standard, rather than being caused by [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).